# Using Kotlin's scope functions in not exhaustive with / when

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I'm pretty new with `Kotlin` and I'm trying to figure out Kotlin's `scope functions`.

My code looks like this:

```
with(something) {
 when {
   equals("test") -> var1 = "test123"
   startsWith("test2") -> var2 = "test456"
   contains("test3") -> myNullableVar?.let { it.var3 = "test789" }
  }
}
```

So before I entered the third check with the `.let` function my `with` function does not need to be exhaustive (I'm not returning something, I'm only doing assignments). In my third check I'm using `.let` as a null-check ... but only for an assignment of `it.var3` (if it is not `null`). I don't need to return anything while I know that Kotlin's `.let` function returns the result of the body by standard.

Nevertheless now my `with/when` needs to be exhaustive otherwise it won't compile anymore.

This got me thinking and trying out different things. I found these ways to solve this issue:

1. I can add an `else` to my `with/when` so it becomes exhaustive but actually I don't need an else and I don't want to use it in this case.
2. I can add another `.let`, so it looks like this: `myNullableVar?.let { it.var3 = "test789" }.let{}` .... but this looks kinda hacky to me. Is it supposed to work like this?
3. Use `If(xy==null){...}else{...}` stuff but I thought I can solve this with Kotlin differently

Because I'm new with Kotlin I'm not really sure how to handle this case properly. I would probably just go with my second idea because "it works". Or should I don't use `.let` for null-checks? Add another empty .`let{}`? Or did I not get the null-safety concept at all? I feel a little bit lost here. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an unfortunate combination of features…

A `when` can be non-exhaustive only when it doesn't return a value.  The problem is that the `with()` function *does* return a value.  And since the `when` is at the bottom, its value is what gets returned, so in this case it must be exhaustive.

So why doesn't it insist on an `else` branch even if you omit the "test3" branch?  That's because assignments don't yield a value.  (They evaluate to `Unit`, which is Kotlin's special type for functions that don't return a useful value.)  If every branch gives `Unit`, then Kotlin seems<sup>*</sup> to be happy to infer a default branch also giving `Unit`.

But the "test3" branch returns something else — the type of `myNullableVar`.  So what type does the `when` infer?  The nearest common supertype of that type and `Unit`, which is the top type `Any?`.  And *now* it needs an explicit `else` branch!

So what to do?

You've found a few options, none of which is ideal.  So here are a few more, ditto!

- You could return an explicit `Unit` from that branch:

  ```
    contains("test3") -> { myNullableVar?.let { it.var3 = "test789" }; Unit }
  ```
- You could return an explicit `Unit` from the `with()`:

  ```
            contains("test3") -> myNullableVar?.let { it.var3 = "test789" }
        }
        Unit
    }
  ```
- You could give an explicit type for the `with()`.  (It has *two* type parameters, so you'd need to give both, starting with the type of its parameter):

  ```
    with<String, Unit>("abc") {
  ```

I haven't found a single obvious best answer, I'm afraid…

And to answer your last question: yes, `?.let{` is perfectly idiomatic and common for null checks.  In this particular case, replacing it with an `if` happens to solve the type problem:

```
contains("test3") -> { if (myNullableVar != null) myNullableVar.var3 = "test789" }
```

But as well as being long-winded, if `myNullableVar` is a property and not a local variable, then it opens up a race condition (what if another thread sets it to null in between the test and the assignment?) so the compiler would complain — which is exactly why people use `let` instead!

---

<sup>(* I can't find a reference for this behaviour.  Is there an official word on it?)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So it seems no solution is ideal. But actually I like the option to return an explicit `Unit` from the `with()`... it looks like the most minimal invasive way to avoid `when` to be exhaustive. And looks better than multiple empty `.let{}`